# Confused about the domain of this function

Tags: functions

The textbook seeks the domain of $f/g$, where $ f(x)= \sqrt {x }$ and $g(x) = |x-3|$. The answer stated is $(0,\infty]$. I have two questions here:

1. Shouldn't $3$ be excluded from the domain as one can't divide by zero?
2. Is it okay to use square brackets for infinity? I have never seen infinity included in the domain of any function before, and my teacher clearly stated that infinity is always followed by a parenthesis, not a square bracket. The answer to a similar problem seeking the domain of $g(x) = |x-3|$ is (-$\infty$,$\infty$]. How? Please explain this as well.

Comment: What textbook is it? The text may have some… strange definitions.

Comment: @Bonnaduck It's the 14th edition of Thomas' Calculus. Surprises me that such a widely used book has such...strange definitions.

Comment: What is $f/g(\infty)$? Or is $(0,\infty]$ just a typo?

Comment: Which page? If it were $(0,\infty)$, it would be the correct domain for $g/f$ rather than $f/g$.

Comment: @HansLundmark I suppose so. As PaulFrost said, perhaps the f and g got mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct on both counts, and are missing one other count. Because $f$ is defined at $0$, and $g$ is defined and nonzero at $0$, $\frac fg$ is also defined at $0$.

The expression $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{|x-3|}$ is defined for values of $x\in[0,3)\cup(3,\infty)$. Your textbook sounds weird and might be using some nonstandard notation, but without knowing the textbook, I can't be the judge of that.

Comment: It's the 14th edition of Thomas' Calculus.

Comment: @AmbicaGovind I don't have access to the book, so all I can say is that the correct answer is $[0,3)\cup(3,\infty)$. I don't know why the answer in the book is $(0,\infty]$, but in commonly used mathematical notation, that answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that the autor mixed $f$ and $g$. In fact $\frac{|x-3|}{\sqrt{x}}$ is defined on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Even that doesn't really explain the closed brackets at infinity though...